# Why does VS Code show wrong JSDoc for array items props?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

JSDoc on VS Code is displaying props as an object instead of an array.

[image]

You can test it yourself by hovering your mouse on the function name in this [codesanbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-brattain-8k0ik?file=/src/index.js:240-243).

According to [JSDoc documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html), it should be able to document:

- a prop value via object destructuring: `@param {string} employee.name`
- array items props, like so: `@param {string} employees[].name`

I couldn't find any limitation regarding JSDoc support on [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_jsdoc-support) either.

Would that be an issue on VS Code, JSDoc or the way I'm documenting my JavaScript functions?

**Note**: I'm aware there's a workaround for this using `@typedef` like below, but I'm more interested in knowing why the documentation doesn't work as I expect.

```js
/**
 * A standard user
 * @typedef {Object} User
 * @property {number} id - The unique ID for the user.
 * @property {string} name - The user name.
 */

/**
 * Foo bar.
 * @param {Object} props - The props.
 * @param {User[]} props.users - A list of users.
 */
function foo(props) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure as to why exactly the `[]` notation isn't properly recognised. I have found this alternative (without resorting to `@typedef`) which seems to be close to what you want:

```js
/**
 * Foo bar.
 * @param {Object} props - The props.
 * @param {Array<{id:number, name:string}>} props.users - A list of users.
 */
function foo(props) {

}
```

> JSDoc supports Closure Compiler's syntax for defining array and object types.

So we can use `Array<>` and record notations as defined here:
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System

Couple of screenshots:

I admit this doesn't look like VS Code does understand that notation:

[image]

However when you start accessing the `props.users` elements it looks better:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me I was able to fix via adding .* to the object param as described
here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36356#issuecomment-577691380

```
/**
 * Provides utils functions that handles multi steps flow
 * with progress bar
 * @param.* {Object} params configuration object
 * @param {number} params.steps total number of steps `Min steps: 2`
 * @param {number} params.initialStep step entry point `Default: 1`
 * @returns {boolean} boolean value
 */
```

and this how it looks

[image]